# get the response parameters of my request

Tags: docusignapi

I went to send my application to the production environment and received the following message.
Excessive polling does not comply with DocuSign rules and limits
I will have to implement the API Resource Limits,
how can I get the following Headers from my answers?
I'm using java jdk how am I going to get the header response parameters?

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = createEnvelopesApi(session.getBasePath(), user.getAccessToken());
EnvelopeDefinition envelope = makeEnvelope(args, obj);
EnvelopeSummary sumary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(session.getAccountId(), envelope);
```

in java we don't have the CreateEnvelopeWithHttpInfo method as in C#. How will I get to control requests?

Answer (score 1):

[Excessive polling](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/go-live/troubleshooting/) most likely is caused because you are requesting information about the same envelope again and again (technically when you [go-live](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/go-live/) it means you did this more than once in 15 min). You don't need to fix this by checking the headers to see the numbers of calls that you made within the allotted window of your [resource limit](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/resource-limits/).

Instead I would suggest to use a web hook with [DocuSign Connect](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/). This approach means you will know when something changed and you won't need to constantly poll the same envelope.